# Not getting reputation change notifications

Tags: bug, reputation, notifications

I'm not getting the little green notification saying +NN anymore when my reputation changes. Anyone else having this problem?

Comment: How long ago did you get the reputation that hasn't shown up yet?

Comment: I've suggested several edits and had them approved, today and yesterday. I also had an answer accepted 10 or 15 minutes ago.

Comment: not sure the timing of getting the notifications, but one thing to be aware of is the notification doesn't show up when your "recent" reputation is negative.  You lost a bunch of points in the last few days due to downvotes, so until the positive rep gain is more than the neg rep gain, it's not going to show

Comment: And I the score is aggregated across all sites.  You set a bounty on MSE 2 days ago.  So that -150 is actually why you likely aren't seeing notification.  Your "positive" rep gain isn't more than the rep you lost across both sites.  Once you gain 150 total (plus whatever else you lost in downvotes), you should start seeing notifications again

Comment: Thanks. Could you add that additional information into the question though, instead of as comments (which might disappear at any time)?

Comment: But I'm pretty sure I red notifcations for rep loss...any way, I right now have more rep that I've ever had. I've stopped getting notifications since [the last two outages (Oct 30 & 31)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371236).

Comment: Oh @psubsee2003, that makes sense. Darn then, wish I'd knew that...

Comment: Cross site dupe; https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209021

Comment: Yeah, you set 150 2 days ago and haven't gained enough since to "overcome" the 150 point loss.  I could be wrong, which is why i didn't make it an answer.  But seems likely

Comment: The reputation change which is used to determine if you will be notified in the topbar of a reputation change is calculated from the last time you opened the topbar "awards" popup on any SE page. If the change in your *overall* reputation on all SE sites from that point to current is not positive, then you won't be notified. If that change is positive, then you should be notified by a green badge applied to the "awards" icon in the topbar. When you open the awards popup from the topbar, that icon-badge will be removed and a new start point for the calculation will be set.

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense actually, because the notifications themselves reflect network-wide rep changes.